# Change WooCommerce Shop Page Button Text for Grouped Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

At the moment it reads "View products" i'd like to change that to "Compare Deals" anyone know how?

I tried...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );

function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text()  {

    global $product;
    $product_type = $product-> product_type;

    switch ( $product_type ) {
        case 'external':
            return __( 'Buy product', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
        case 'grouped':
            return __( 'Compare Deals', 'woocommerce' ); <<<<<<<<<
        break;
        case 'simple':
            return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
        case 'variable':
            return __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
        default:
            return __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' );
    }

}
```

But it has no effect on the grouped products on the /shop page it only changes the add to cart buttons or external button links - the buttons I am trying to change on the /shop page still read "View products" these are not actual add to cart buttons these are "LoopProduct-link" buttons I am trying to change the buttons lead to the product from the shop page.

Comment: `woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text` is for the *single* product page. In the loop the filter is `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text`

Comment: Yes that works thanks

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and post the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );

function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text()  {

global $product;
$product_type = $product-> product_type;

switch ( $product_type ) {
    case 'external':
        return __( 'Buy product', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'grouped':
        return __( 'Compare Deals', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'simple':
        return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'variable':
        return __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    default:
        return __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' );
}

}
```

Kudos to helgatheviking for the tip...

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems the hook "woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text" has been depricated, and not working. whereas the latest one "**woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text**" working just fine.

Use the same code above with the latest hook.